# Alternative to MS Excel for non-calculating (text & images) tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-word, project-management

In my company and in millions of other companies, Excel is misused for word processing (creation of tables containing mainly text, for example project plans and lists of all sorts), basically just because no one knows an alternative, or because people can't be bothered to use the tables function in Word.

Excel is totally unsuitable for this because of its awkward and limited text editing functions. The worst is however that you can't easily insert images into cells, as you can in Word tables, for example.

Therefore, project plans, lists, tables and the likes created in Excel tend to be mostly awful and everyone hates them: they look awful, they are awful to use, edit and present, they are fiddly, they don't contain images and graphics, etc. pp.

Does anyone know of an alternative program, with the following features:

- easy handling of (basically unlimited size) tables
- easy insertion of images **into** cells like in MS Word
- focus on word processing rather than math/calculation

Comment: Uhm... Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some of the Excel alternatives like LibreOffice Calc or Google Sheets? The latter recently introduced the ability to insert images into cells.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that Google Sheets has learned how to do this, this is great.

However, I'm more looking for a locally installable "mainstream" application that is accessible to the typical Office worker.